# VIM: vim.command('y') works as expected but vim.command('gv') starts the GUI instead of visual select

Tags: vim

```
function! Cut()
python3 << EOF
import vim

cw = vim.current.window
pos = cw.cursor
cr = vim.current.range
vim.command('y')
vim.eval('gv')
#print(cr)

EOF
endfunction
```

I select a bunch of lines manually. Then type *M-x* to cut. The above function is invoked. I run 'y' to yank lines, now i need to reselect 'gv' and then 'd' delete. Unfortunately,
it's doing **:gv** vs plain-old *gv* - is there some other vim.command that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to observe the *modes* those commands apply. `gv` is a *normal mode* command, but `vim.command()` takes an *Ex command* (from *command-line mode*), as per the `:help python-command`:

```
vim.command(str)
        Executes the vim (ex-mode) command str.  Returns None.
```

So, your `y` is interpreted as `:yank`, and `gv` as `:gvim`, explaining the behavior you're seeing.

Fortunately, there's an Ex command to run normal mode commands, the aptly named `:normal`. So, the solution is to use

```
vim.command('normal! gv')
```

(The `!` avoids considering mappings and is recommended.)

Answer (score 0):

vim.command(':normal! gv') (thanks to tek0 on Freenode #vim IRC)